# How can Linux hibernation be enabled under UEFI Secure Boot on RHEL / RockyLinux / AlmaLinux?

Tags: rhel, uefi, hibernate, secure-boot

When running under UEFI Secure Boot with a current Linux distribution, "kernel lockdown" will be instated. Multiple kernel messages along the lines of

`Lockdown: swapper/0: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7`

point you to the fact that your kernel will not attempt to hibernate, unless you provide it with a secure (i.e. signed/encrypted) swap space that it recognizes.

I assume that the three mentioned distributions are similar enough so that one solution fits all. With UEFI and signed executable code, I am somewhat unsure whether this assumption holds, though.

What is the recommended way to enable **Secure-Boot + Hibernation** on one of the mentioned (sibling) distributions? And, ideally: From which release on is it supported?

Comment: In case you don't know Matthew Garrett's article on what needs to work for Secure Boot + Hibernation: [it's recommended reading.](https://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/55845.html)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thank you for the reference. 

My question asking for the "recommended" way is meant to provoke an answer which helps a user to get this going without compiling any C code.

Comment: Yep, understand the intention. I haven't managed to make hibernation work in this scenario either, I just feel I understand better why I didn't.

Comment: I know that work on this has been performed since 2011, therefore I am wondering how this patch by Matthew Garrett relates to that.
This article is from 2013: 
https://itwire.com/business-it-news/open-source/60546-suse-working-on-using-kexec-hibernation-on-secure-boot